# Detecting when a tcp client is not active for more than 5 seconds

Tags: python, tcp, send

Im trying to make a tcp communication, where the server sends a message every x seconds through a socket, and should stop sending those messages on a certain condition where the client isnt sending any message for 5 seconds.
To be more detailed, the client also sends constant messages which are all ignored by the server on the same socket as above, and can stop sending them at any unknown time. The messages are, for simplicity, used as alive messages to inform the server that the communication is still relevant.

The problem is that if i want to send repeated messages from the server, i cannot allow it to "get busy" and start receiving messages instead, thus i cannot detect when a new messages arrives from the other side and act accordingly.

The problem is independent of the programming language, but to be more specific im using python, and cannot access the code of the client.

Is there any option of receiving and sending messages on a single socket simultaneously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use two threads, one will write to the socket and the second will read from it.

This works since sockets are full-duplex (allow bi-directional simultaneous access).

**Option 2**

Use a single thread that manages all keep alives using `select.epoll`. This way one thread can handle multiple clients. Remember though, that if this isn't the only thread that uses the sockets, you might need to handle thread safety on your own

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in another answer, threads are one common approach.  The other approach is to use  an event loop and nonblocking I/O.  Recent versions of Python (I think starting at 3.4) include a package called `asyncio` that supports this.

You can call the `create_connection` method on an event_loop to create an `asyncio` connection.  See [this example](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html) for a simple server that reads and writes over TCP.

In many cases an event loop can permit higher performance than threads, but it has the disadvantage of requiring most or all of your code to be aware of the event model.